# Can't download dependencies or run this project

Tags: go, github, dependencies

Hi there I'm very new to GO and am just trying to run this github project as I'm interested in the subject of automation.

The github link is: https://github.com/Swan/Nothing

After cloning the repository and trying to 'go mod download' I get nothing.

Comment: `go mod download` doesn't print anything if it works. What problem are you having using the project? That's not a `main` package, if you are trying to use that in another project you don't need to to manually clone the repo, or do anything with it.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. I found this repo on github and really wanted to get it working but I just don't know how

Comment: What do you mean by "get it working"? It has no main package, so it does nothing on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only use this package in your own project. It is not meant to run by it self as it has no main package.

If you want to use it or play with it, create your own project, import the package and use it in your own code.